# How to write multiple ssid's and passwords to the same json file ESP32

Tags: json, esp32, platformio, arduino-esp32

I am currently testing a piece of code using arduinojson6. My goal is to store multiple ssid's and passwords to the esp32 SPIFF.

The uneddited question contained a piece of code that would append to the file rather than reading doc, deleting /SSID.json, adding to doc serialization and saving the file again like I have now, is also not the solution.

the desired json file would be:

```
{"information":[{ "SSID":"variable blaat1", "PASS1":"variable Abc1", "NUMBER": "1" },{ "SSID":"variable blaat2", "PASS2":"variable Abc2", "NUMBER": "2"  },{ "SSID":"variable blaat3", "PASS3":"variable Abc3", "NUMBER": "3"  },{ "SSID":"variable blaat4", "PASS4":"variable Abc4", "NUMBER": "4"  },{ "SSID":"variable blaat5", "PASS5":"variable Abc5", "NUMBER": "5"  }]}
```

Instead, when more then 1 value is serialized and appended it will read like this:

```
    {
  "information": {},
  "test": [
    "mooiman\n",
    "mooiweer\n"
  ],
  "number": [
    1,
    2
  ]
}
```

Maybe some of you know how to serialize it properly.

The code I test with:

```
#include <Arduino.h>
#include <WiFi.h>
//#include <time.h>
//#include <ESP32Ping.h>
#include "FS.h"
#include "SPIFFS.h"
//#include <HTTPClient.h>
#include <ArduinoJson.h>


int numberofInputs = 1;

String ssid = "YourSSID";
String passwords = "YourPassword";

String readString;

char FileReadBuff[1024];

DynamicJsonDocument doc(1024);


void readFile(fs::FS &fs, const char * path){
   if (SPIFFS.exists("/SSID.json") == false)
  {
   File file = SPIFFS.open("/SSID.json", FILE_WRITE);
 
   if (!file) {
    Serial.println("There was an error opening the file for writing");
    return;
  }
 
  if (file.print("SSID")) {
    Serial.println("File was written");
  } else {
    Serial.println("File write failed");
  }
  file.close();
 }
    Serial.printf("Reading file: %s\r\n", path);

    File file = fs.open(path);
    if(!file || file.isDirectory()){
        Serial.println("- failed to open file for reading");
        return;
    }
    uint16_t i = 0;
    Serial.println("reading");
    while (file.available()) {
    FileReadBuff[i] = file.read();
    i++;
  }
    file.close();
}
void CleanFile(fs::FS &fs, const char * path, const char * message) {
  for( int i = 0; i < sizeof(FileReadBuff);  ++i ){
  FileReadBuff[i] = (char)0;
  }
  File file = SPIFFS.open(path, FILE_WRITE);
  if (fs.remove(path)) {
    Serial.println("\r\n- file cleaned");
  } else {
    Serial.println("\r\n- Cleaning failed");
  }
  file.print(path);
  
}
void appendFile(fs::FS &fs, const char * path, const char * message){
   if (SPIFFS.exists("/SSID.json") == false)
  {
   File file = SPIFFS.open("/SSID.json", FILE_WRITE);
 
   if (!file) {
    Serial.println("There was an error opening the file for writing");
    return;
  }
 
  if (file.print("SSID")) {
    Serial.println("File was written");
  } else {
    Serial.println("File write failed");
  }
  file.close();
 }
    Serial.printf("Appending to file: %s\r\n", path);

    File file = fs.open(path, FILE_APPEND);
    if(!file){
        Serial.println("- failed to open file for appending");
        return;
    }
    if(file.println(message)){
        Serial.println("- message appended");
    } else {
        Serial.println("- append failed");
    }
    file.close();
}

void Deserialization(){
 

  for( int i = 0; i < sizeof(FileReadBuff);  ++i ){
  FileReadBuff[i] = (char)0;
  }

  readFile(SPIFFS, "/SSID.json");  //read everything from ssid.json file
  const char * JsonFF = FileReadBuff; // put everything in to const char
  Serial.print("Json From File:"); Serial.println(JsonFF);
  
  DeserializationError error = deserializeJson(doc, JsonFF);
  if(error){
     Serial.print(F("deserializeJson() failed: ")); Serial.println(error.f_str()); // if not legit print error
  }
  if(!error){
    String information = doc["information"];

     Serial.println(information);
     information = "";
  }
}

void testjson(){


  readString = "";

while(readString.length() < 1) {
  while (Serial.available()) {
    delay(10);  //small delay to allow input buffer to fill
    if (Serial.available() > 0) {
      char c = Serial.read();  //gets one byte from serial buffer
      if (c == ',') {
        break;
      }  //breaks out of capture loop to print readstring
      readString += c;
    } //makes the string readString
  }
  if (readString.length() > 0) {
    Serial.println(readString); //prints string to serial port out

    if (readString.indexOf("READ") >= 0) {
      Serial.println("reading file");
      readFile(SPIFFS, "/SSID.json");
      
      Serial.println(FileReadBuff);

      for( int i = 0; i < sizeof(FileReadBuff);  ++i ){
       FileReadBuff[i] = (char)0;
      }
      
    }
    if (readString.indexOf("DES") >= 0) {                      //DEZ deserialize will result in an error because json file is currently not valid 
      Serial.println("reading deserialized json");
      Deserialization();
      
    }
    if (readString.indexOf("CLEAN") >= 0) {                    //CLEAN cleans the SSID.json file
      Serial.println("reading deserialized json");
      CleanFile(SPIFFS, "/SSID.json", "");
    }
    
    if (readString.indexOf("WRANDOM") >= 0){                   //WRANDOM writes a random string to the SSID.json file
      readString = "";
      Serial.println("Going to write the following input:");   //waiting for user input
      while(readString.length() < 1) {
       while (Serial.available()) {
        delay(10);  //small delay to allow input buffer to fill
        if (Serial.available() > 0) {
        char c = Serial.read();  //gets one byte from serial buffer
        if (c == ',') {
        break;
        }  //breaks out of capture loop to print readstring
        readString += c;
    } //makes the string readString
  }
  if (readString.length() > 0) {
    Serial.println(readString); //prints string to serial port out
    `here is the part we're talking about`
      CleanFile(SPIFFS, "/SSID.json", "");
      JsonObject information = doc.createNestedObject("information");

      String SerializedJson = "";

      doc["test"].add(readString);
      doc["number"].add(numberofInputs);
      
      serializeJsonPretty(doc, SerializedJson);
     
      appendFile(SPIFFS, "/SSID.json", SerializedJson.c_str());
      SerializedJson = "";
      numberofInputs ++;
      return;

     }
    }
   }
  }
 }
}


void setup() {
  // put your setup code here, to run once:
   Serial.begin(115200);
    if (!SPIFFS.begin(true)) {
      Serial.println("An Error has occurred while mounting SPIFFS");
   return;
  }
  
  if (SPIFFS.exists("/SSID.json") == false)
  {
   File file = SPIFFS.open("/SSID.json", FILE_WRITE);
 
   if (!file) {
    Serial.println("There was an error opening the file for writing");
    return;
  }
 
  if (file.print("SSID")) {
    Serial.println("File was written");
  } else {
    Serial.println("File write failed");
  }
  file.close();
 }
   WiFi.mode(WIFI_MODE_STA);

   WiFi.begin(ssid.c_str(), passwords.c_str());

   while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED) { //Check for the connection
    delay(1000);
    Serial.print(".");
    }

  Serial.println("Connected");


}

void loop() {
  // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:
  readString = ""; //clears variable for new input
  Serial.println("Ready for new input: ");
  testjson();
}
```

So when you serial write WRANDOM you'll get promted to put in something.
When that is recieved it will store that in json.
Do that another time.
Next when you serial write READ it will show you the saved /SSID.json.

Thanks in advance.

Note that the DynamicJsonDocument startsof empty.

PS. I know littlefs is the new spiff but lets first try to make this work (or I need to make sepperate files for every ssid+password)

Comment: ArduinoJson provide an [assistant](https://arduinojson.org/v6/assistant/) tool for you to create the code you need.

Comment: I know and im trying to figure out how my json structure should be and how to serialize/deserialize that.

Comment: Are you JSON bound? You could also make a tiny struct with the info you need and just write binary to a specific partition on the ESP32 flash and with the known struct size just add them each after another.

Comment: I think so, it’s because json is the way to store information seperatly. Also it is also probably not the only thing I need to do in Json.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a test sketch you can implement to your project.
I did not had the time to write more detailed sketch than this.

Let me know if you have any question about this

```
#include <Arduino.h>
#include "FS.h"
#include <LittleFS.h>
#include <ArduinoJson.h>

#define DOC_SIZE 5000

/*
Example JSON :
{
  "information":[
    { "SSID":"variable blaat1", "PASS1":"variable Abc1", "NUMBER": "1" },
    { "SSID":"variable blaat2", "PASS2":"variable Abc2", "NUMBER": "2"  },
    { "SSID":"variable blaat3", "PASS3":"variable Abc3", "NUMBER": "3"  },
    { "SSID":"variable blaat4", "PASS4":"variable Abc4", "NUMBER": "4"  },
    { "SSID":"variable blaat5", "PASS5":"variable Abc5", "NUMBER": "5"  }
  ]
}
*/

/*
  When you create a JSON array, you don't need to push the index of the object, since you can later
  ask for the array size, therefor you know the indexes. Also you don't need to separate the passwords
  like PASS1 or PASS2 since every cred is a separate object.
*/
void addCredentials( const char* SSID, const char* PW ){
    // Create a static JSON document.
    StaticJsonDocument fileDoc(DOC_SIZE);
    // Open the file containing the credentials
    File credFile = LittleFS.open(FILE_PATH,FILE_READ);
    // Check if it opened.
    if( !credFile ){ Serial.println("Failed to open file"); return; }
    // Deserialize the file
    DeserializationError error = deserializeJson(fileDoc, credFile );
    // Check if the deserialization has any errors.
    if( error ){ Serial.printf("Error on deserialization: %s\n", error.c_str() );
    // Get the info array from the JSON.
    JsonArray infoArr = fileDoc["information"].as<JsonArray>();
    // Create a new object inside the array.
    JsonObject newCred = infoArr.createNestedObject();
    // Add credentials to the object.
    newCred["SSID"] = SSID;
    newCred["PASS"] = PW;
    // Serialize everythig back to the file.
    serializeJson(fileDoc, credFile);
    // Close the file.
    credFile.close();
}

// Open the file and put the pretty json into the serial directly.
void printFileContent(){
  File credFile = LittleFS.open(FILE_PATH,FILE_READ);
  if( !credFile ){ Serial.println("Failed to open file"); return; }
  serializeJsonPretty(Serial, credFile);
  credFile.close();
}

void clearFile(){
  if( !LittleFS.exists(FILE_PATH) ){ Serial.println("Credentials file does not exists yet!"); return; }
  File credFile = LittleFS.open(FILE_PATH,FILE_READ);
  credFile.remove();
}

void getUserInput(){
  if( !Serial.available() ){ return; }
  // Get the credentials or whatever from the serial
  // and call the **addCredentials( const char* SSID, const char* PW );** function.
}


void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);
}

void loop() {
  getUserInput();
}
```

Comment: Is it correct you don't write to the file? I was trying it with SPIFF but will try littlefs if that is what it takes to make it work

Comment: I noticed you need to serialize to String first. you cant go directly to the file, otherwise you'd get a number 1. I'm not sure what that 1 stands for but it should be something like serializeJson(fileDoc, String you defined) then after you should do something like file credfile2 = LittleFS.open(FILE_PATH, FILEWRITE); so it will save the old + newadded credentials right?

Comment: Nice I figured out how to get [
  {
    "SSID": "sadly\n",
    "PASS": "sadly\n"
  },
  {
    "SSID": "hallo\n",
    "PASS": "hallo\n"
  }
]

Answer (score 0):

I got it figured out with help from Dr.Random. It wasn't the full answer but it helped getting the json format and apend to that file correctly. The following code is a working example.

```
#include <Arduino.h>
#include <WiFi.h>
#include "FS.h"
#include "LittleFS.h"
#include <ArduinoJson.h>


#define FORMAT_LITTLEFS_IF_FAILED true
#define DOC_SIZE 5000
#define FILE_PATH "/SSID.json"

String ssid = "yourssid";
String passwords = "yourpass";

String readString;

char FileReadBuff[1024];


void readFile(fs::FS &fs, const char * path){
    Serial.printf("Reading file: %s\r\n", path);

    File file = fs.open(path);
    if(!file || file.isDirectory()){
        Serial.println("- failed to open file for reading");
        return;
    }

    Serial.println("- read from file:");
    while(file.available()){
        Serial.write(file.read());
    }
    file.close();
}


void Showone(int wichone){
  DynamicJsonDocument doc(DOC_SIZE);

  File credFile = LittleFS.open(FILE_PATH, FILE_READ);// open file for reading
  DeserializationError error = deserializeJson(doc, credFile);// deserialize json
  if( !credFile ){ Serial.println("Failed to open file"); return; }// if file doesn't exist, return 
   
  const char* SSID = doc[wichone]["SSID"]; //
  const char* PASS = doc[wichone]["PASS"]; // 

  Serial.print("SSID and PASS = "); Serial.print(SSID); Serial.print(PASS); Serial.print(" "); Serial.println(" ");
  
  credFile.close();

}

void addCredentials(const char * input){
  DynamicJsonDocument doc(DOC_SIZE);// create json doc
  String Serialized; // create string to store serialized json

  File credFile = LittleFS.open(FILE_PATH, FILE_READ);// open file for reading

if( !credFile ){ Serial.println("Failed to open file"); return; }// if file doesn't exist, return
    
DeserializationError error = deserializeJson(doc, credFile);// deserialize json
if( error ){ Serial.printf("Error on deserialization: %s\n", error.c_str() );} //error when spiff is empty or not formatted correctly

JsonArray inforArr = doc["information"].as<JsonArray>();// get array from json


JsonObject newCred = doc.createNestedObject();// create new object in json
newCred["SSID"] = input;
newCred["PASS"] = input;

 
serializeJsonPretty(doc, Serialized);
Serial.print("input = "); Serial.println(input);
Serial.print("Serialized: "); Serial.println(Serialized);

File credFile2 = LittleFS.open(FILE_PATH, FILE_WRITE);// open file for writing

credFile2.print(Serialized);

credFile2.close();
credFile.close();
Serialized = "";      

}

void testjson(){


  readString = "";

while(readString.length() < 1) {
  while (Serial.available()) {
    delay(10);  //small delay to allow input buffer to fill
    if (Serial.available() > 0) {
      char c = Serial.read();  //gets one byte from serial buffer
      if (c == ',') {
        break;
      }  //breaks out of capture loop to print readstring
      readString += c;
    } //makes the string readString
  }
  if (readString.length() > 0) {
    Serial.println(readString); //prints string to serial port out

    if (readString.indexOf("READ") >= 0) {
      Serial.println("reading file");
     readFile(LittleFS, "/SSID.json");
      
      Serial.println(FileReadBuff);

      for( int i = 0; i < sizeof(FileReadBuff);  ++i ){
       FileReadBuff[i] = (char)0;
      }
      
    }
    if (readString.indexOf("SHOW") >= 0) {
     readString = "";
      Serial.println("Showing the following input(number): ");   //waiting for user input
      while(readString.length() < 1) {
       while (Serial.available()) {
        delay(10);  //small delay to allow input buffer to fill
        if (Serial.available() > 0) {
        char c = Serial.read();  //gets one byte from serial buffer
        if (c == ',') {
        break;
        }  //breaks out of capture loop to print readstring
        readString += c;
    } //makes the string readString
  }
  if (readString.length() > 0) {
     Serial.println(readString); //prints string to serial port out
     Showone(readString.toInt());

     }
    }
      
    }
    if (readString.indexOf("CLEAN") >= 0) {                    //CLEAN cleans the SSID.json file
      Serial.println("reading deserialized json");
      File credFile = LittleFS.open(FILE_PATH, FILE_WRITE);// open file for writing
      credFile.print("");
      credFile.close();
    }
    
    if (readString.indexOf("WRANDOM") >= 0){                   //WRANDOM writes a random string to the SSID.json file
      readString = "";
      Serial.println("Going to write the following input:");   //waiting for user input
      while(readString.length() < 1) {
       while (Serial.available()) {
        delay(10);  //small delay to allow input buffer to fill
        if (Serial.available() > 0) {
        char c = Serial.read();  //gets one byte from serial buffer
        if (c == ',') {
        break;
        }  //breaks out of capture loop to print readstring
        readString += c;
    } //makes the string readString
  }
  if (readString.length() > 0) {
     Serial.println(readString); //prints string to serial port out
     addCredentials(readString.c_str());

     }
    }
   }
  }
 }
}

void setup() {
  // put your setup code here, to run once:
   Serial.begin(115200);

   if(!LittleFS.begin(FORMAT_LITTLEFS_IF_FAILED)){
        Serial.println("LittleFS Mount Failed");
        return;
    }
    //if /ssid.json doesn't exist, create it littlefs
    if(!LittleFS.exists(FILE_PATH)){
        Serial.println("File doesn't exist, creating it");
        File credFile = LittleFS.open(FILE_PATH, FILE_WRITE);
        if(!credFile){
            Serial.println("Failed to create file");
            return;
        }
        credFile.close();
    }

   WiFi.mode(WIFI_MODE_STA);

   WiFi.begin(ssid.c_str(), passwords.c_str());

   while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED) { //Check for the connection
    delay(1000);
    Serial.print(".");
    }

  Serial.println("Connected");

}
void loop() {
  // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:
  readString = ""; //clears variable for new input
  Serial.println("Ready for new input: ");
  testjson();
}
```

Any improvements are still desirable.